# Write cvs files with two columns in python

Tags: python-2.7, nlp

l have two column that l want to write into a csv file using python2.7.

the first column is a set of word  such as:

```
['ee','aeoiete', 'aatriexa', 'reaaet','cnle','aeocoee','etlancoret']
```

the second column is

```
['hi','ok', 'ok', 'what','are','you','now']
```

column 1 and two have the same length.
I tried two ways:

1)

```
column1= set_of_words_1
column2= set_of_word2_2
temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[column1,column2]], columns = ['words_1', 'word2'])
temp_df.to_csv('/home/words.csv)
```

I got all the words of column1 in the same line and all the word of column2 in the same line. But I want to get each word in a new line.
in the first line of first column I got:

```
'ee','aeoiete', 'aatriexa', 'reaaet','cnle','aeocoee','etlancoret'
```

rather than

```
'ee',
'aeoiete',
 'aatriexa', 
'reaaet',
'cnle',
'aeocoee',
'etlancoret'
```

2) I tried also the following:

```
with open('home/ahmed/internship/results.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp,delimeter=',')
    data=[['words_1', 'words_2'],[column1],[column2]]
    a.writerows(data)
```

I got the following error

> TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'words_1': column1, 'words_2': column2})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @elyase , it's workoing but l get three columns instead of two. The first column contains numbers which represent the number of the row .0 1 2 ...... second column it is "column2" and column3 it is "column1"

Comment: This is normal for a DataFrame. The first column you are getting is called the index. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.